# Distincts of all the columns to list from a Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a data frame like below and I want to convert to expected format as distinct values in a list.

```
+---------------------+---------------+
|col1                 |col2           |
+---------------------+---------------+
|                  A  |             1 |
|                  B  |             2 |
|                  C  |             1 |
|                  D  |             1 |
|                  A  |             2 |
|               null  |             1 |
+---------------------+---------------+
```

Expected Format

```
+---------------------+---------------+
|col1                 |col2           |
+---------------------+---------------+
|      [A,B,C,D,null] |         [1,2] |
+---------------------+---------------+
```

Is there any wany to solve the above problem.??

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
import spark.implicits._

df
  .na.fill("null", Seq("col1"))
  .agg(
     func.collect_set($"col1").alias("col1"),
     func.collect_set($"col2").alias("col2")
  )
```

Comment: But collect_set is ignoring null values in that column. I want that null value to be in that array.

Comment: @Learnis: You could convert the null to a string "null" before using the above method. (Also there is no need to include `groupBy(lit(""))`, just use `agg` directly on the dataframe - this will remove the need for the `select` at the same time).

Comment: I have added @shaido suggestions, generating a "null" String might not be what you want but you could use it as a workaround